# Why does pylance not provide help text for anything other than the Smartsheet class?

Tags: vscode-extensions, smartsheet-api, pylance

I have been coding with the smartsheet sdk, which has a bunch of modules and classes but pylance only has suggestions and defintions for the Smartsheet class, which the only real use I have for that is the inital api call of:
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(API_key)

All of the useful functions that do things with your client like `smartsheet_client.Sheet.get_sheet(sheet_id)`, pylance has no idea what they are.

Other things like selenium, sqlalchemy, pandas, psycopg2, etc all have helpful information and colored formatting on their methods like you'd expect - it's just this that it's happening with. I've tried reinstalling, and at this point I think it's either a config issue I have no idea how to deal with, or the smartsheet package is structured in such a way that I just have to suck it up.

Here is the documentation of the [package structure](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-python-sdk/py-modindex.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Pylance, but a brief internet search turned up this potentially helpful article about Pylance config settings in Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing.

In particular, the [Troubleshooting Intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_troubleshooting-intellisense) section of that article may be helpful for resolving the problem you've described. Perhaps try editing the [Code analysis settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_code-analysis-settings) as speicified in this documentation?

[image: Troubleshooting causes & solutions]

Comment: I did initially try some of these suggestions and went through and tried them in a different way now, I am starting to think the problem might just be that due to the way the package is coded in a dynamic way, where you instance a class with an API key then call things off that instance rather than a static package.module.method() PyLance just isn't able to understand it. It's only picking up what's in the init.py, and no matter how I mess with the init or do import X from Y, I can't get it to recognize the structure that the API needs

Comment: Okay, sorry my feedback wasn't helpful. As a next step, I was going to suggest that you create an issue in the [smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/issues) GitHub repo to seek Smartsheet's input on this problem -- but it looks like Smartsheet archived this repo (and all other SDK repos) earlier this year -- so you can no longer log issues there. What an odd thing for them to do. As an alternative, you might consider posting to the [API & Developers](https://community.smartsheet.com/discussions/tagged/api-and-developers) forum.

Comment: FYI -- I found out that Smartsheet has moved the Python SDK repo on GitHub (and archived it in the old location). The new location is here: https://github.com/smartsheet/smartsheet-python-sdk. You might consider opening an issue in that repo to seek feedback about the issue you're seeing -- perhaps someone at Smartsheet can shed light on how to fix it.

Comment: I'll do that! Thanks for the help either way!